# $f$ absolutely contininuous $\Rightarrow f\cdot\sin$ absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I wonder whether, if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is an absolutely continuous function, multiplying it by $\cos\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}$ or $\sin\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}$ results in another absolutely continuous function continuous, i.e.: are the functions defined by $g(x)=f(x)\cos\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}$ or $h(x)=f(x)\sin\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}$ absolutely continuous? If they are, how can it be seen?

That is what I understand from the fact that Kolmogorov and Fomin seem [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf) to use that fact in integrating the Fourier coefficient of the periodic absolutely continuouws function $f$ by parts, where I think that the equality, valid for an absolutely continuous function, $\int_{[a,b]}f' d\mu=f|_a^b$ is used.

Thank you very much for any answer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product of two absolutely continuous functions on a closed bounded interval is absolutely continuous.

Hint:  $$|f(x) g(x) - f(y) g(y)| \le |f(x)| |g(x) - g(y)| + |g(y)| |f(x) - f(y)|$$

Comment: I $\infty$-ly thank you!